Why do I need to use the "rebuild PE Header" option when adding an import with CFF EXPLORER?
I used the CFF EXPLORER Import Adder function for days, by just using the option "rebuild import table" and nothing else. Everything was fine for days.
Suddenly one day the application I added the imports to, stopped functioning by just not executing, and nothing was done to the application, then I discovered using a debugger, that it was because of an exception, which is not shown when you run the application without the debugger.
After some tries I finally discovered that after importing functions, I had to use the rebuild PE Header function of CFF EXPLORER to get the application running, why was this suddenly happening when I never had problems before?
The strange thing is, that even if I use the rebuild PE Header option of CFF EXPLORER on the already patched application that suddenly stop working, still does not work, so the trick only works if I import a function in a new exe file and then after that use rebuild PE Header.
